# How to test for folder existence using testthat in R

Tags: r, testthat

I have a function that will set up some folders for the rest of my workflow

```
library(testthat)

analysisFolderCreation<-function(projectTitle=NULL,Dated=FALSE,destPath=getwd(),SETWD=FALSE){
  stopifnot(length(projectTitle)>0,is.character(projectTitle),is.logical(Dated),is.logical(SETWD))

  # scrub any characters that might cause trouble
  projectTitle<-gsub("[[:space:]]|[[:punct:]]","",projectTitle)

  rootFolder<-file.path(destPath,projectTitle)
  executionFolder<-file.path(rootFolder,if (Dated) format(Sys.Date(),"%Y%m%d"))

  subfolders<-c("rawdata","intermediates","reuse","log","scripts","results")

  dir.create(path=executionFolder, recursive=TRUE)
  sapply(file.path(executionFolder,subfolders),dir.create)
  if(Setwd) setwd(executionFolder)

}
```

I am trying to unit test it and my error tests work fine:

```
test_that("analysisFolderCreation: Given incorrect inputs, error is thrown",
{
  # scenario: No arguments provided
  expect_that(analysisFolderCreation(),throws_error())
})
```

But my tests for success, do not...

```
 test_that("analysisFolderCreation: Given correct inputs the function performs correctly",
 {
   # scenario: One argument provided - new project name
   analysisFolderCreation(projectTitle="unittest")
   expect_that(file.exists(file.path(getwd(),"unittest","log")),
               is_true())
 }
```

Errors with

1. Error: analysisFolderCreation: Given correct inputs the function performs correctly ---------------------------------------------------------------
   could not find function "analysisFolderCreation"

As I am checking for a folder's existence, I'm unsure how to go about testing this in an expectation format that includes the function analysisFolderCreation actually inside it.

I am running in `dev_mode()` and executing the test file explicitly with `test_file()`

Is anyone able to provide a way of rewriting the test to work, or provide an existence checking expectation?

Comment: Sorry but I don't see what `test_that(` is? Where have you defined it in the code?

Comment: @SimonO101: The OP has failed to make clear that he is using Hadley's testthat package.

Comment: @DWin thanks! I found `RUnit` but couldn't find any corresponding functions in that package.

Comment: Your test fails because R `could not find function "analysisFolderCreation"` (this happens before your `expect_that(file.exists ...` statement is called). Do you `source` the file or load your package before? (I don't really know `dev_mode()` and `test_file()`.)

Comment: execute `analysisFolderCreation(projectTitle="unittest")` before `test_that`, not inside. Note that you have to clean up after the test.

Comment: @EDi, I've moved the functions out of the tests, but it only works if I load the function into my workspace - I suspect from sgibb's comment in combination with the workspace notion that unless I'm running the full test() statement, I will have to do this for running individual test files. I'll continue playing and update with more info.

Comment: @SimonO101 Apologies - I stated it in the thread title but forgot to mention it explicitly in the body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appeared to be the use of test_file().  Using test() over the whole suite of unit tests does not require the function already be created in the workspace unlike test_file().